# getChild() method makes error

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have expandable list view in my application. Data is stored in this way:

```
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;   
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;    
    Map<String, String> m;
```

When i use method `getChild()`:

```
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.childData.get(groupData.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }
```

It makes error in `groupData.get(groupPosition))`

How to solve it?

Comment: can you paste your error here ?

Comment: Please add a stacktrace you're getting.

Comment: Error:(666, 24) error: no suitable method found for get(Map<String,String>)
method ArrayList.get(int) is not applicable
(actual argument Map<String,String> cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method AbstractList.get(int) is not applicable
(actual argument Map<String,String> cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding something
- arraylist works with integer position key

so -> `groupData.get(groupPosition)` returns String
then you can't do `childData.get(groupData.get(groupPosition))`

Also you should consider a list like that =>

```
HashMap<String,<Map<String, String>> values;
```

here you have parent/child with only one list.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm a beginner..and what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String,<Map<String, String>> values;
```

with that :

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    String key = values.keyset().get(groupPosition); //Father key look how words hashmap on oracle site;
    parentElement = values.get(key);
    childKey = parentElement.keyset().get(childPosititon);
    return parentElement.get(childKey)
}
```

I have not factorized code to let you understand how it works. Take a look as i said, at how workds list/Map/Set. It is really important and will help you to do a cleaner code.

Comment: and how should i fill HashMap?